# Hide '/index.html' from URL on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am hosting a static website on Google Cloud Platform using storage buckets and have set the main page suffix to 'index.html' as shown in [Google's tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), however, I am still getting a bounce to ./dir/index.html from ./dir .

When requesting ./dir/ it serves back 'index.html' without changing the URL which is what I want but it doesn't do that if a user requests without the trailing forward slash.

Removing the main page suffix completely works for each format except for ./dir .

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Might this help you? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467971/how-to-hide-html-extension-in-url-from-google-app-engine-cloud-hosting/51502231?noredirect=1#comment90051559_51502231