# how to hide .html extension in URL from google app engine (cloud hosting)

Tags: google-app-engine, url, url-rewriting, web, app.yaml

I uploaded my webpage using google app engine and it is working fine. It is a very simple webpage with 6 static files (.html all of them)

I need to Remove .html extension from URL.
For example: I have www.example.com/contact.html, I want www.example.com/contact

My current app.yaml is

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: website/index.html
  upload: website/index.html

- url: /
  static_dir: website
```

All html files are Inside the "Website" folder, so how can i hide .html extension from URL

So Please help me to fix it.

Comment: I don't know if this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573485/php-htaccess-pretty-url-in-reverse but anyway, this is a duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936791/how-to-remove-html-extensions-from-google-cloud-platform-url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have just 6 static files and you do not want to use .htaccess, you have to do this:

Instead of

```
> handlers:
> 
> - url: /   static_dir: website
```

You could:

```
handlers:

- url: /
  static_files: website/index.html
  upload: website/index.html

- url: /file1
  static_files: website/file1.html
  upload: website/file1.html

- url: /file2
  static_files: website/file2.html
  upload: website/file2.html

- url: /file3
  static_files: website/what_ever_name.what_ever_format
  upload: website/what_ever_name.what_ever_format
```

Comment: Since it works to you I would appreciate if you accept the answer in order to help the community to quickly locate a answer which works.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, but you'll have to not rely on the existing catch-all `static_dir` handler you have at the end, since that will never be reached due to the new catch-all handler expanding any other file pattern with a `.html` extension:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: website/index.html
  upload: website/index.html

# handler for specifically requested .html files
- url: /(.*\.html)$
  static_files: website/\1
  upload: website/.*\.html$

# add any other more specific file patterns here, before the catch-all case below

# catch-all handler implicitly serving .html files, no handler below it will be reached
- url: /(.*)$
  static_files: website/\1.html
  upload: website/.*\.html$

# no other handler from this point forward will be reached
```

Side note: overlapping handler url patterns for `static_dir` and `static_files` may cause problems, see [Static files are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447890/static-files-are-missing/33448239#33448239)

Comment: when i use above code i get an `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The request is invalid.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: 'Value "website/\1" must be a valid regular expression. Details
:
      invalid escape sequence.'
    field: version.handlers[1].static_files.upload_path_regex
  - description: 'Value "website/\1.html" must be a valid regular expression. De
tails:
      invalid escape sequence.'
    field: version.handlers[2].static_files.upload_path_regex` and what about **1** from `static_files: website/\1`

Comment: Apologies, I messed up the `upload` statements. I updated the answer